# How to copy nested child (by foreign key)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Have two tables created with code first. They have relation one to many between them.

```
public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

So I create one instance of Foo foo1, which has a list of Bars. Then I create another instance of Foo foo2 and I want it to have all foo1 Bars.

If I do this:

```
var bar = new Bar {
    Name = "Bar 1"
};
var bar2 = new Bar
{
    Name = "Bar 2"
};
var foo = new Foo
{
    Name = "Foo 1",
    Bars = new List<Bar> { bar, bar2 }
};
_db.Foos.Add(foo);
_db.SaveChanges();

var foo2 = new Foo
{
    Name = "Foo 2",
    Bars = foo.Bars.ToList()
};
_db.Foos.Add(foo2);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Then foo2 will have all foo1 Bars, but foo1 will have none. 
So I am doing something like this:

```
var bars2 = new List<Bar>();
foreach (var _bar in foo.Bars)
{
    bars2.Add(new Bar
    {
        Name = _bar.Name
    });
}

var foo2 = new Foo
{
    Name = "Foo 2",
    Bars = bars2
};
```

But it just doesn't seem right to me. Isn't there a much cleaner way to do this? I tought that EF would understand and handle this automatically.

Comment: use tag c# for c# questions. C is a completely different language.

Comment: @BodoThiesen Sorry, it was a mistake.

Comment: No need to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to clone your list before assigning it to foo2

```
.
.
var foo2 = new Foo
{
    Name = "Foo 2",
    Bars = foo.Bars.Select(bar => (Bar)bar.Clone()).ToList();
};
.
.
```

By This way you will get a new copy of the list.

**Update:**
Extend your entity to implement ICloneable.

Do not forget to put the partial class under the same namespace

```
public partial class Bar: ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        bar.Name = Name;
        return bar;
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

You can use MemberwiseClone() if you only need a simple copy.

```
.
.
public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
.
.
```

Sorry I forgot to past the interface code.

Comment: I could not find that EF would have a 'Clone' method in any namespace.